# embed ion-header-bar within ionic template using angularJS's ng-include

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I've added following code to my html template:

```
<div ng-include src="'templates/header.html'"></div>
```

my header.html file contains:

```
<ion-header-bar align-title="center" class="bar-navigation">
    <p class="center">TEST Include</p>
</ion-header-bar>
```

it's not rendering the ion-header-bar.

**Does anyone know how to get this working please ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Renaming the file header.html into header.tpl.html fixed my problem.

That's because gruntfile.js includes tpl.html files only.

The included ion-nav-bar is not visible though, but I guess that's a different issue.

Thanks to @Andrew for helping out.

Answer (score 0):

As per the ngInclude documentation at: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude

You use `src` when `ng-include` is being used as the element. eg.

```
<ng-include src="templates/header.html"></ng-include>
```

Otherwise, provide the template location as the value of the ng-include attribute.

```
<div ng-include="templates/header.html"></div>
```

Also, remove the single quotes from your template source, they are not necessary.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't find the doc very clear. Where to declare the directive ? I have added the following line to my controller angular.module('myModule', ['ngInclude']). Anything else needed ?

Comment: ngInclude is built into the angular framework. What you are doing in your previous comment is trying to load it as a module. Remove `'ngInclude'` from between the []'s. If `myModule` is your only module and you are using ionic, then you should be loading the ionic module.

Comment: Perhaps check out http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/ ...once you have installed ionic with npm you can run the command `ionic start myApp tabs` in an empty directory. This will create a simple demo ionic app. This is very helpful in seeing how angular and ionic work together.

Comment: Also, if you're new to Angular. I highly recommend https://egghead.io/technologies/angularjs. Short, sharp, and simple tutorials.

Comment: I have removed the single quotes, and the 'ngInclude' from between the []'s. Still not working

Comment: no log, I just don't see the content of header.html in my template

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/GXclS9AsL15ujRmLWsaG?p=preview ...it's working now. Removed scripts and only using `ionic-bundle.js` as this contains everything you need. Missing opening tag in `header.html`. Modified `ng-include` to element and turns out I was wrong, you do need single quotes. Apologies. Seems that your date box is being hidden behind the header, but the header is now showing. Case closed.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the plunk, but it's still not working in my environment